# Different result with in_array() and isset()

Tags: php, isset

I have an array $box_activ like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => categories
    [1] => add_a_quickie
    [2] => last_viewed
    [3] => whats_new
    [4] => wishlist
)
```

By checking with

```
in_array('categories', $box_activ)
```

the result is *true*.

Why do I get *false* as result by checking with

```
isset($box_activ['categories'])
```

I thought isset() is the more performance method of in_array().

Comment: check this http://blog.straylightrun.net/2008/12/03/tip-of-the-day-codeissetcode-vs-codein_arraycode/

Answer (score 1):

Because one checks if an index/key in the array is set, while the other checks if an equal value is assigned to any of the indexes/keys in the array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => categories
    [1] => add_a_quickie
    [2] => last_viewed
    [3] => whats_new
    [4] => wishlist
)
```

0, 1, 2, 3, 4 is the indexes/keys, and categories, add_a_quickie etc is the values each index has.

```
isset($box_activ[0])
# should then return true.
```

To traverse the array with key and value:

```
foreach($array AS $key=>$value)
```

The array in PHP works pretty much like a hashmap in that strings can be indexes/keys too:

```
$array['some string'] = 'some value';
echo $array['some string'];
# should print 'some value' to screen.
```

Comment: Ok, my mistake this really works. Is there a way to change it instead of typing the indexes?

Comment: I saw you commented with some foreach loop... I will update my answer with how to traverse the entire array with key and value.

Comment: That's what I tried a few minutes ago. I also tried it with array_flip() so I needn't to change many code parts.

Answer (score 0):

`$box_activ['categories']` gets the element indexed by `categories` in the array `$box_activ`. That element does not exist since `categories` is the value of the element at index `0`.

`isset` is indeed faster than `in_array`, but that is `in_array` has to loop over an entire array, while `isset` only has to check the variable you passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

`isset($box_activ['categories'])` returned false because `categories` is an element try `isset($box_activ[0])`

Answer (score 0):

There is no value in the Array with a key of 'categories'. The key for categories is 0, so to use isset, you would have to get the key for that value..

```
$key = array_search('categories', $box_activ);
```

and then

```
isset($box_activ[$key])
```

will be true, although there is no need to check that because array_search has already verified that there is a value of categories in the array

Comment: Is there a way to change this with an additional key? Actually the following foreach-loop looks like `foreach ($boxes as $box) {
  if (in_array($box, $box_activ)) {
    require_once DIR_WS_BOXES . $box . '.php';
  }
}``